# $.ajax success event not fired in submit context [jQuery 1.2.1]

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a strange problem. Searched for solution but couldn't find anything.
I'm intercepting some 3rd party code on submit (submit cancelled cause method return false).
I want to submit the form when my ajax call is completed so it is not aborted by ongoing submit.

The problem is that success callback is never called. Also in that version of jquery, $.ajax does not return XHTR.

```
RegisterReservation: function() {
    var data = 'HotelName=' + encodeURIComponent($('#resData>div:nth-child(1)').text()) +
        '&From=' + encodeURIComponent($('#resData>div:nth-child(3)').text()) +
        '&To=' + encodeURIComponent($('#resData>div:nth-child(4)').text()) +
        '&TotalPrice=' + encodeURIComponent($('.totalPriceBg').text()) +
        '&FirstName=' + encodeURIComponent($('#firstName').val()) +
        '&LastName=' + encodeURIComponent($('#lastName').val()) +
        '&PhoneNumber=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=phoneNumber]').val()) +
        '&EmailAddress=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=emailAddress]').val());

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://server/api/WhiteLabel",
        data: data,
        type: 'GET', 
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
success: function(data){alert("SUCCESS");}
    });
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Consider using a version of jQuery that is less than 5 years old.

Comment: If the data var came from a form, why don't you use $('#formId').serialize() ?

Comment: Tried to update jquery but it collides with currently referenced library from html. Html is not mine. I can only inject some JS in some placeholders...

Comment: Or create a JSON object instead of your data string

Comment: cross domain POST requests were denied

Comment: $('#formId').serialize()  - do not want to send all data from the form, only some of them. Also some data is acquired not from inputs but from span, p, etc.

Comment: If success isn't happening, most likely error is. Do proper debugging!!!! Add an error handler and inspect the values of the three arguments. *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."* Why didn't your ajax call work?

Comment: @KevinB error handler is also not called. I've checked that. Debugged script. I see request in firebug. Server receives it.

Comment: if success and error aren't being called, you should be getting a basic javascript error, such as a same-origin-policy error. What are you using to see errors?

Comment: Also, the crossDomain option doesn't exist in jquery 1.2 (and isn't needed in your case anyway, it's almost NEVER needed, even on cross-domain requests. The only time it is needed is if you're making a same-domain request and want to treat it as cross-domain.)

Comment: I gave up. I'm sending data to parent window and making ajax call from there. There it works perfectly.

Thank you all for trying to help me!